# Ajax doesn't respond or it seems like that

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use ajax for a dynamic comment section, everything seems to be right, but when it comes to functionality something's wrong because I don't receive any alert messages it simply doesn't give me anything to think about when I click it, that's it nothing happens, this is the code...

Route -

```
Route::resource('/comments', 'CommentsController');
```

Ajax -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitComment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/comments') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                body: $('#commentBody').val(),
                post_id: $('#post_id').val()
            },
            success: function(result){
                $('.alert').show();
                $('.alert').html(result.success);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

create.blade -

```
<h1>Create comment</h1>
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'myForm']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'commentBody', 'placeholder' => 'Share your thoughts related to this post']) }}
</div>
{{ Form::hidden('post_id', $post->id) }}
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

CommentsController@store -

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);


    // Create Comment
    $comment = new Comment;

    $comment->body = $request->body;
    $comment->user_name = auth()->user()->name;
    $comment->post_id = $request->post_id;
    $comment->profile_picture = auth()->user()->profile_picture;

    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Comment Created');
}
```

Comment: Input with id `#submitComment` isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple example and I hope useful for you :

my `Ajax` :

```
 <script>
        var urlVisit="{{route('comments.store')}}"
        var token = "{{csrf_token()}}"
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlVisit,
            data: {
                place_id: 1,
                _token: token
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('ok')

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if (xhr.status == 419)
                {
                    alert(xhr.responseText) // text of error

                    // do something
                }
                else if(xhr.status == 401)
                {
                    // do something
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('No')
                }

            }

        });
    </script>
```

and my `CommentsController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{

    public function store()
    {
        //  DO something (validate or save to database,...)
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Comment Created'],200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you create the id `submitComment` that you are looking for in `$('#submitComment')`

Can use the form submit event instead

Change

```
$('#submitComment').click(function(e){
```

To

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
```

Comment: Still no response

Comment: Put a console log or alert inside to make sure event occurs for starters

Comment: Also are you repeating ID's in page? Like in a loop?

Comment: @Nikola also, your controller returns a redirect and a session message, neither will work like that when using ajax

Comment: when I run network status 200 type xhr name comments

Comment: return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']); this is what I've changed in the cntroller

Comment: The console says csrf token not found so I am working on it